# Adminer Editor Login - Password missing

Tags: php, editor, adminer

I am currently trying to setup the simple adminer editor version. I am not sure why but I have problems understanding how adminer is working with its password data which lead to the following question:
How can I pass the password data to the credential function of adminer editor?

What I am using:

- Adminer Editor - Compact database editor
- @version 4.3.1
- with PHP7 / NGINX

What I tried so far:
the login part:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr><th><?php echo lang('Username'); ?><td><input type="hidden" name="auth[driver]" value="pgsql">
      <input id="username" name="auth[username]" value="<?php echo h($_GET["username"]); ?>" autocapitalize="off">
    <tr><th><?php echo lang('Password'); ?><td><input type="password" name="auth[password]" autocapitalize="off">
</table>
```

And my credentials function:

```
function credentials() {
      // server, username and password for connecting to database
      $DB_USER=$_POST['auth[username]'];
      $DB_PASSSWORD=$_POST['auth[password]'];
      //$DB_PASSWORD=get_password();

      // server, username and password for connecting to database
      return array('myhost', $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
    }
```

Anything I do - It always claims that it has no password. Their documentation describes the function `get_password()` which can be used to get the password from the session - but either I am too stupid or it is just not my day.

Comment: What exactly is your end goal here? Are you trying to integrate Adminer into one of your site's pages?

Comment: Hey, yes, this was the original intent. I wanted to build an adminer interface with user login but not database credentials.

Comment: Can you provide information about which user should have access? How will the Adminer installation be used?